# Cambiar nombre de archivo subido a PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Un saludo cordial para todos

Tengo un formulario en HTML que captura unos datos, entre ellos un archivo que puede contener cualquier formato. Dichos datos son procesados por otro archivo PHP, que almacena el archivo en una carpeta y los demas datos en una base de datos mysql.

ARCHIVO 1: captura los dastos

```html
 <form action="pse_guardar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="text" id="estudiante" name="estudiante" value =" <?php echo $e_id ?>" readonly><br>

  <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" required><br>

  <select name = "tipo">
   <option>Selecciona</option>
   <option>Excusa ausencia</option>
   <option>Ausencia futura</option>
   <option>Salida en jornada</option>
   <option>Excusa uniforme</option>
   <option>Llegada tarde</option>
  </select><br>

  <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion" required><br>

  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" > <br>

  <input type="submit" name="" value="Almacenar">

 </form>
```

ARCHIVO 2: Toma los datos y los almacena

```html
<?php

  $estudiante = $_POST["estudiante"];
 $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
 $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
 $descripcion = $_POST ["descripcion"];
 $directorio = "archivos/pse/";

 if (!file_exists($directorio)) 
      {
        mkdir($directorio, 0777, true);
      }

 $archivo = $directorio . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

 $tipoArchivo = strtolower(pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"] ["tmp_name"], $archivo)) {
          echo "archivo subido con exito";

        } else {
          echo "error en la subida del archivo";
        }

    $adjunto = $archivo;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabladelabasededatos (estudiante, fecha, tipo, descripcion, adjunto) values ('$estudiante', '$fecha', '$tipo', '$descripcion', '$adjunto')";

    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    if ($consulta==false) {
        echo "Error en la consulta";

        } else {
          echo "<br><br>Datos almacenados exitosamente<br><br>";
               }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo "<a href ='" .$adjunto . "'>Descargar archivo</a>";




 ?>
```

Pregunta:

Cómo puedo cambiar el nombre del archivo subido de tal manera que el sistema, por ejemplos les vaya asignando un nombre como 001, 002, 003, 004?... porque asi como está el sistema me reemplaza los arhivos cuando tienen nombres iguales

Comment: agregarle un número luego del nombre y antes de la extensión ( `nombre-001.ext` ) ? o cada archivo empieza en `000-nombre.ext` y va subiendo ?

Comment: Hola alo Malbarez, que cuando se suba el archivo el sistema automaticamente les cambie el nombre, por ejemplo archivo01.pdf, archivo02.pdf, archivo03.pdf

Comment: si el número sólo es importante para ordenar alfabéticamente podes agregarle al nombre del archivo [`time()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) , y para evitar colisiones sumarle [`uniqid( $estudiante, true )`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución es usar el mismo ID del registro de la base de datos. Así:

```html
<?php
    $estudiante = $_POST["estudiante"];
    $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
    $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
    $descripcion = $_POST ["descripcion"];
    $directorio = "archivos/pse/";
    if (!file_exists($directorio))
        mkdir($directorio, 0777, true);
    $tipoArchivo = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    //EL CAMPO DE LA TABLA LLAMADO ADJUNTO DEBERÍA SER EL LA EXTENSIÓN DEL ARCHIVO Y EL ID AUTOINCREMENTAL SERÍA El NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabladelabasededatos (estudiante, fecha, tipo, descripcion, adjunto) values ('$estudiante', '$fecha', '$tipo', '$descripcion', '$tipoArchivo')";
    if (!mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
        echo "Error en la consulta";
    } else {
        echo "<br><br>Datos almacenados exitosamente<br><br>";
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $adjunto = $directorio . $id . "." . $tipoArchivo)) {
            echo "archivo subido con exito";
        } else {
            echo "error en la subida del archivo";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo "<a href ='" .$adjunto . "'>Descargar archivo</a>";
?>
```

Ten en cuenta que el campo *adjunto* de la tabla, ahora almacena la extensión del archivo, y el ID autoincremental será el nombre.

Otra opción sería que cambiaras el nombre del archivo por la fecha con hora, minutos y segundos concatenar esto con un numero aleatorio de *N* cifras en caso de que simultáneamente más de un usuario esté cargando archivos, pero me parece mas confiable la primera opción.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho por la respuesta, pero no me funciono... si guarda el archivo, pero no le pone nombre, y genera algunos errores a la hora de ejecutar, si lo vuelvo a ejecutar reemplaza el archivo que crea.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMonsalve hice unos pequeños ajustes. Revisa de nuevo y me cuentas.

Comment: @ Daniel Pérez agradezco mucho tu colaboración pero sigue sin funcionar... me genera dos errores: Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\wamp\www\02SCGIP\pse_guardar.php on line 29. Y ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\02SCGIP\pse_guardar.php on line 29

Creo que vale la pena recordar que los unicos campos que tengo en la base de datos son:

        $estudiante = $_POST["estudiante"];
 $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
 $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
 $descripcion = $_POST ["descripcion"];
 $directorio = "archivos/pse/";

Comment: Disculpa, la variable $link en realidad era conexión xD es que estoy tan acostumbrado a usarla así que ni me percaté. @JuanCarlosMonsalve Prueba y me cuentas, estaré atento.

Comment: Bueno, ahora si me está subiendo los archivos y les está cambiando el nombre... pero no me está guardando la ruta del archivo ni el nombre, en la consulta que yo tengo, como yo lo tenía si me guardaba la ruta y el archivo, asi: archivos/pse/dos.pdf

Comment: Hola @Daniel Pérez, te cuento que ya lo organicé, simplemente anexé al final una nueva consulta sql para actualizar el registro, de tal manera que el sistema me almacene la ruta completa, después de todo el código que vos colocaste, le agregué este:     $consulta="UPDATE tabla set estudiante='$estudiante', fecha='$fecha', tipo='$tipo', descripcion='$descripcion', adjunto='$adjunto' where id_pse=$id"; 
    
    $resultados=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

Te agradezco muchisimo por la ayuda, mil y mil gracias.

Comment: Un gusto, amigo.