# Renombrar imagen y delimitar a subir solo formato png y jpg

Tags: php, imagen

Tengo un formulario en el cual básicamente es subir imágenes (lo hace sin problemas y la mueve a una carpeta), pero lo que quiero hacer es que la renombre y que le asigne al azar solo números y letras, de igual forma delimitar que solo suban imágenes en formato png y jpg.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?php
session_start();
include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de dat


//Imagen 1    
   
    $imagen1        = $_FILES["imagen1"]["name"];
    $r1         = $_FILES["imagen1"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino1   = "../photos/".$imagen1;
    $d1          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen1;

//Imagen 2
    $imagen2        = $_FILES["imagen2"]["name"];
    $r2         = $_FILES["imagen2"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino2   = "../photos/".$imagen2;
    $d2          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen2;
    
//Imagen 3
    $imagen3        = $_FILES["imagen3"]["name"];
    $r3         = $_FILES["imagen3"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino3   = "../photos/".$imagen3;
    $d3          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen3;
    
//Imagen 4
    $imagen4        = $_FILES["imagen4"]["name"];
    $r4         = $_FILES["imagen4"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino4   = "../photos/".$imagen4;
    $d4          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen4;
    
    
//Imagen 5
    $imagen5        = $_FILES["imagen5"]["name"];
    $r5         = $_FILES["imagen5"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino5   = "../photos/".$imagen5;
    $d5          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen5;

//Imagen 6
    $imagen6        = $_FILES["imagen6"]["name"];
    $r6         = $_FILES["imagen6"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino6   = "../photos/".$imagen6;
    $d6          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen6;

//Imagen 7
    $imagen7        = $_FILES["imagen7"]["name"];
    $r7         = $_FILES["imagen7"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino7   = "../photos/".$imagen7;
    $d7          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen7;  
    
//Imagen 8
    $imagen8        = $_FILES["imagen8"]["name"];
    $r8         = $_FILES["imagen8"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino8   = "../photos/".$imagen8;
    $d8          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen8;  
    
//Imagen 9
    $imagen9        = $_FILES["imagen9"]["name"];
    $r9         = $_FILES["imagen9"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino9   = "../photos/".$imagen9;
    $d9          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen9;  
    
//Imagen 10
    $imagen10        = $_FILES["imagen10"]["name"];
    $r10         = $_FILES["imagen10"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino10   = "../photos/".$imagen10;
    $d10          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen10;    
    
//Imagen 11
    $imagen11        = $_FILES["imagen11"]["name"];
    $r11         = $_FILES["imagen11"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino11   = "../photos/".$imagen11;
    $d11          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen11;    
    
//Imagen 12
    $imagen12        = $_FILES["imagen12"]["name"];
    $r12         = $_FILES["imagen12"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino12   = "../photos/".$imagen12;
    $d12          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen12;    
    
//Imagen 13
    $imagen13        = $_FILES["imagen13"]["name"];
    $r13         = $_FILES["imagen13"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino13   = "../photos/".$imagen13;
    $d13          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen13;    
    
//Imagen 14
    $imagen14        = $_FILES["imagen14"]["name"];
    $r14         = $_FILES["imagen14"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino14   = "../photos/".$imagen14;
    $d14          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen14;    
    
//Imagen 15
    $imagen15        = $_FILES["imagen15"]["name"];
    $r15         = $_FILES["imagen15"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino15   = "../photos/".$imagen15;
    $d15          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen15;    
    
//Imagen 16
    $imagen16        = $_FILES["imagen16"]["name"];
    $r16         = $_FILES["imagen16"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino16   = "../photos/".$imagen16;
    $d16          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen16;    
    
//Imagen 17
    $imagen17        = $_FILES["imagen17"]["name"];
    $r17         = $_FILES["imagen17"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino17   = "../photos/".$imagen17;
    $d17          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen17;    
    
//Imagen 18
    $imagen18        = $_FILES["imagen18"]["name"];
    $r18         = $_FILES["imagen18"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino18   = "../photos/".$imagen18;
    $d18          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen18;    
    
//Imagen 19
    $imagen19        = $_FILES["imagen19"]["name"];
    $r19         = $_FILES["imagen19"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino19   = "../photos/".$imagen19;
    $d19          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen19;    
    
//Imagen 20
    $imagen20        = $_FILES["imagen20"]["name"];
    $r20         = $_FILES["imagen20"]['tmp_name'];
    $destino20   = "../photos/".$imagen20;
    $d20          = "../CABI/photos/".$imagen20;    

    

$id=$_POST['valora_id'];
$sql="update inventario_inmueble  
set 

imagen1=\"$destino1\",  imagen1='$d1',
imagen2=\"$destino2\",  imagen2='$d2',
imagen3=\"$destino3\",  imagen3='$d3',
imagen4=\"$destino4\",  imagen4='$d4',
imagen5=\"$destino5\",  imagen5='$d5',
imagen6=\"$destino6\",  imagen6='$d6',
imagen7=\"$destino7\",  imagen7='$d7',
imagen8=\"$destino8\",  imagen8='$d8',
imagen9=\"$destino9\",  imagen9='$d9',
imagen10=\"$destino10\",  imagen10='$d10',
imagen11=\"$destino11\",  imagen11='$d11',
imagen12=\"$destino12\",  imagen12='$d12',
imagen13=\"$destino13\",  imagen13='$d13',
imagen14=\"$destino14\",  imagen14='$d14',
imagen15=\"$destino15\",  imagen15='$d15',
imagen16=\"$destino16\",  imagen16='$d16',
imagen17=\"$destino17\",  imagen17='$d17',
imagen18=\"$destino18\",  imagen18='$d18',
imagen19=\"$destino19\",  imagen19='$d19',
imagen20=\"$destino20\",  imagen20='$d20'


where id= '$id'";
print_r($sql);
$query_update= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($query_update){
    if($r1 != ""){
        copy($r1, $destino1);
        
    }
    if($r2 != ""){
        copy($r2, $destino2);
    }
    if($r3 != ""){
        copy($r3, $destino3);
    }
    if($r4 != ""){
        copy($r4, $destino4);
    }
    if($r5 != ""){
        copy($r5, $destino5);
    }
    if($r6 != ""){
        copy($r6, $destino6);
    }
    if($r7 != ""){
        copy($r7, $destino7);
    }
    if($r8 != ""){
        copy($r8, $destino8);
    }
    if($r9 != ""){
        copy($r9, $destino9);
    }
    if($r10 != ""){
        copy($r10, $destino10);
    }
    if($r11 != ""){
        copy($r11, $destino11);
    }
    if($r12 != ""){
        copy($r12, $destino12);
    }
    if($r13 != ""){
        copy($r13, $destino13);
    }
    if($r14 != ""){
        copy($r14, $destino14);
    }
    if($r15 != ""){
        copy($r15, $destino15);
    }
    if($r16 != ""){
        copy($r16, $destino16);
    }
    if($r17 != ""){
        copy($r17, $destino17);
    }
    if($r18 != ""){
        copy($r18, $destino18);
    }
    if($r19 != ""){
        copy($r19, $destino19);
    }
    if($r20 != ""){
        copy($r20, $destino20);
    }
    
    
    
   print_r($sql);
        $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            if ($query_new_insert){         
                $messages[] = "El eqipo ha sido ingresado satisfactoriamente.";
                    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                    window.location.href="inmueble.php";
                        </script>';
            } else{
                $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
            }
}else{
    $errors[] = "Algo salió mal, intentalo más tarde ".mysqli_error($con);
}
if(isset($errors)){
    ?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"> &times;</button>
    <strong>Error!</strong>
    <?php
                foreach($errors as $error){
                    echo $error;
                }
            ?>
  </div>
  <?php
}
if(isset($messages)){
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
      <?php
            foreach($messages as $message){
                echo $message;
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se hace este UPDATE en la BD? `imagen1=\"$destino1\",  imagen1='$d1' ...` ¿No se sobreescribe la columna?

Comment: @aeportugal, SI TAMBIÉN TENGO ESE PROBLEMA QUE SE SOBRESCRIBEN, SI QUIERO SUBIR OTRAS IMÁGENES SE BORRAN LAS ANTERIORES Y SE INSERTAN LAS NUEVAS ESE ES UN ERROR QUE TENGO :(

Answer (score 0):

para la parte de las extensiones puedes usar
`$extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` el cual recupera el nombre de la extensión, para la parte de renombrar puedes mirar la siguiente respuesta ya publicada [Cambiar nombre archivo subido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/268998/cambiar-nombre-de-archivo-subido-a-php) el cual usa el ID de la propia base de datos para dárselo al fichero.

Answer (score 0):

Estas escribiendo demasiado código que puedes reducir drásticamente usando ciclos y funciones.

Suponiendo que tienes un formulario más o menos así:

```
<form action="pagina_que_recibe.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h4>UPLOAD IMAGES</h4>
    <input type="file" name="imagen1" id="el_id"><br />
    <input type="file" name="imagen2" id="el_id"><br />
    <input type="file" name="imagen3" id="el_id"><br />
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Subir Imagenes" name="submit">
</form>
```

Cuando se le da clic a *submit*, se genera una variable superglobal llamada `$_FILES`, la cual tendrá este formato:

```
array(n) { 
    "imagen1" => ["name"=>"val1", "full_path"=>"val2", "tmp_name"=>"val4" ...],
    "imagen2" => ["name"=>"val1", "full_path"=>"val2", "tmp_name"=>"val4" ...], 
    ...
}
```

Entonces conociendo ese comportamiento, se puede hacer algo para no tener que escribir el mismo bloque una y otra vez para cada entrada del formulario.

```
<?php
// ... // Otras llamadas y definiciones (config, mysqli, etc)

define("UPL_PATH", "../photos/");
define("UPL_DB", "../CABI/photos/");

function uploadFile($imgName, $tmpName) {
    $upl_success = false;
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, UPL_PATH.$imgName)) {
        $upl_success = true;
    }
    return $upl_success;
}

// Inicia aqui.
$subquery = array();
foreach($_FILES as $formName=>$values) {
    $imgName = $values['name'];
    $newName = $imgName; // <-- Insertar aqui un nuevo nombre
    $tmpName = $values['tmp_name'];
    if($imgName and uploadFile($newName, $tmpName)) {
        // Si la imagen ha subido satisfactoriamente
        $dbimgname = UPL_DB . $newName;
        $subquery[] = "$formName='$dbimgname'";
    }
}
if($subquery) {
    $to_update = implode(', ', $subquery);
    $sql = "UPDATE inventario_inmueble SET $to_update WHERE id='$id'";
    echo $sql; // <--  Visualizar el query
    // [ ... ] Tus instrucciones para ejecutar el SQL
}
```

Para generar un nombre diferente, puedes usar una semilla como microtime() combinada con la fecha actual. Si decides hacerlo así, reemplazar la línea `$newName = $imgName;`, por las dos primeras líneas de las siguientes instrucciones verificadas en en la consola:

```
> $ext = pathinfo($imgName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // jpg, png, etc...
> $newName = date('Ymd').substr(microtime(false), 2, 6).'.'.$ext;
> echo $newName;
20220310884198.jpg
```

De igual manera, como ya tienes `$ext`, puedes impedir que continúe la carga de esa imagen si `in_array($ext, ['jpg', 'png']);` es `false`.